# How to enable some buttons, when all others are disabled?

Tags: java, android

I have 16 buttons in my game activity. Plus 4 (I will talk about them later), all 4 disabled at this point. Now, whenever a user click on one of those 16 buttons, I set some text to it and then disable it, so it cannot be used again. Is there a way, when all 16 buttons are clicked and disabled, to enable all of those 4 buttons?

Comment: You could of course check a condition each time that one of those 16 buttons is disabled through a single function call.  That function call could check the enable feature of each of your buttons.

Comment: What you describe is a generic state machine, so yes - there is a way to implement that on any computer. What are you using to develop this game, what code have you tried?

Comment: @John I did not try anything, cause I did not know how to approach this problem.

Comment: can you clarify your question bit more, posting some code will be helpful

Comment: Well, I can post here my whole game class but there isn't there anything tided to this problem, cause I haven't tried anything, cause I don't know where to start solving this problem.

Comment: @JaySnayder Can you post some code to show me how that function looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick way to do it:

```
public class example{
    int activeButtons = 16;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //initialize
    }

    /**
    * This is your onClick method
    */
    public void click(View v){
        v.setEnabled(false);
        activeButtons--;
        if(activeButtons == 0){
            enable();
        }
    }

    /**
    * This will enable your four buttons
    */
    public void enable(){
        //Get references to your buttons here
        Button b1 = ...;
        Button b2 = ...;
        Button b3 = ...;
        Button b4 = ...;

        b1.setEnabled(true);
        b2.setEnabled(true);
        b3.setEnabled(true);
        b4.setEnabled(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Very nice idea, I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Be aware that there are tons of other ways to implement this and the best answer can depend on the person. This is how I would do it, but make sure you pick the solution that is easiest for you to understand. Let me know if you need any clarifications or additional solutions.

Answer (score 0):

An example of one way to accomplish what you are asking is simply to set aside a case such as this in your code; if I understand what your question is in regards to what has been posted above:

```
Button buttonOne = null;
//...fourteen buttons
Button otherButtonOne = null;
//...other four buttons

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupButtons();
}

private void setupButtons()
{
    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //..Whatever else you do with button.
            if(allButtonsAreDisabled())
            {
                enableOtherFourButtons();
            }
        }
    });
    //...
}

private boolean allButtonsAreDisabled()
{
    if(!buttonOne.isEnabled()) // && !buttonTwo.isEnabled() && ...
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

private void enableOtherFourButtons()
{
    otherButtonOne.setEnabled(true);
    //...
}
```

Comment: I use switch statement instead of onClickListener. If it helps [here's](https://github.com/Nabukodonosor/spojnice/blob/master/Asocijacije.java) that complete class on GitHub, just to see how it looks.

Comment: Either way, it's just an approach to get the idea, not what you have to use.

Comment: I decided to go with another solution. Thanks for the efort anyway.